# Error while deploy Primefaces-Extensions example, why?

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Error while deploy: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils
The module has not been deployed.

This is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<f:view contentType="text/html" locale="en">
<pe:head title="PrimeFaces Extensions - ShowCase">
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>
    </f:facet>
</pe:head>
<h:body>
    <pe:layout>
        <pe:layoutPane position="north">
            <ui:insert name="header"/>
        </pe:layoutPane>
        <h:form>
            <ui:insert name="center"/>
            <pe:layoutPane position="south">
                <ui:insert name="footer"/>
            </pe:layoutPane>
        </h:form>
    </pe:layout>
</h:body>
```

Comment: how many lib I need??? common-lang3.jar, com.google.gson.GsonBuilder?? how can i begin... using facelet, netbean...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As told in the getting started for primefaces extensions project on https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/wiki/Getting-Started you need to add "Apache Commons Lang3" to your project.

> Add Apache Commons Lang3 to your project if it's not in classpath.

You may download the library from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Comment: I have other problem: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder, I can not download this library because my country  (Cuba) is blocked by google... Can help me for download from other site??

Comment: Maybe you can try maven repository to download the jar http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.3

Answer (score 2):

According to the information written on the [Primefaces Extensions Getting Started](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/wiki/Getting-Started)

PF Extensions Dependencies :

- Add current PrimeFaces JAR file to your project from this [download section](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html).
- Add the last PrimeFaces Extensions JAR file to your project from the [Maven Central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cprimefaces-extensions).
- Add [Apache Commons Lang3](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) to your project if it's not in classpath.
- Add Gson JAR file to your project from the [Gson homepage](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) (optional).
- Add the last JAR file for CKEditor if you need from the [Maven Central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cprimefaces-extensions) (optional).
- Add the last JAR file for CodeMirror if you need from the [Maven Central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cprimefaces-extensions) (optional).
- Add Exporter dependencies [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) and [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) if you use the Exporter component.

Good luck.